# Querying Windows Azure Table Storage with multiple values for single filter condition

Tags: azure, storage

I want to fetch records from azure table storage on the basis of multiple Partition key values.

I was referring below link for query data with multiple criteria:

[Querying Windows Azure Table Storage with multiple query criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167680/querying-windows-azure-table-storage-with-multiple-query-criteria)

[image]

In above image as you can see that there are four records in the table now I want to fetch record based on two partition key values. for example I want to fetch record based on section1 and section2 partition key value.

So my question is can I write a single statement like
`TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "**section1, section2**");` like we write in SQL query.

or we need to write GenerateFilterCondition multiples time for each search criteria.

Answer (score 4):

> So my question is can I write a single statement like
>   TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey",
>   QueryComparisons.Equal, "**section1, section2**"); like we write in
>   SQL query.
>
> or we need to write GenerateFilterCondition multiples time for each
>   search criteria.

As of today, Azure Table Service does not support `IN` like SQL databases so you would need to write multiple filter conditions connected by `OR` logical connector. For example,

```
        var pk1Filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "section1");
        var pk2Filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "section2");
        var pk3ilter = = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "section3");
        var filter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(pk1Filter, TableOperators.Or, TableQuery.CombineFilters(pk2Filter, TableOperators.Or, pk3Filter);
```